# Firewall sending ARP requests for 8.8.8.8

Tags: arp, checkpoint

We have a checkpoint firewall that is having Internet issues today. When I did a packet capture on the interface going into the ISP router I can see ARP messages for the google DNS servers.

[image]

Thats not right is it? It should just be forwarding the packet to the ISP router? The ARP request is making it look as though the firewall thinks that 8.8.8.8 is in the network directly connected to the firewall? Or am I going mad?

We havent made any changes to the config, the firewall has been working fine for years.

```
set interface eth2-07 comments "Internet-500Mb"
set interface eth2-07 link-speed 1000M/full
set interface eth2-07 state on
set interface eth2-07 auto-negotiation on
set interface eth2-07 mtu 1500
set interface eth2-07 ipv4-address x.x.x.68 mask-length 28
add interface eth2-07 alias x.x.x.71/28

set static-route default nexthop gateway address x.x.x.65 on


> show route destination 8.8.8.8
Codes: C - Connected, S - Static, R - RIP, B - BGP (D - Default),
       O - OSPF IntraArea (IA - InterArea, E - External, N - NSSA),
       A - Aggregate, K - Kernel Remnant, H - Hidden, P - Suppressed,
       U - Unreachable, i - Inactive

S               0.0.0.0/0           via x.x.x.65, eth2-07, cost 0, age 8725
```

Comment: Please add the firewall config (interfaces and routing) to your question and especially include the routing table.

Comment: That's the basic appliance configuration. We'd need to see the full configuration - which isn't exportable as text. If you have anything in there that makes the FW act as if it's 8.8.8.8, then it could do this. Also, the kernel routing table doesn't show the entire truth.